# PHP: count the items and echo them

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables:
table 1: topics table

```
topic_id       name      date
1              blue         3/20/14
2              green        3/21/14
3              red          3/22/14
```

table 2: replies table

```
reply_id      topic_id      message 
12            1             bla bla
13            1             bla bla
14            2             bla bla
```

table 3: comments table

```
comment_id    topic_id      message
50            1             bla bla
51            2             bla bla
```

As you can see, the table 2 and 3 are related to the table 1 via the foreign key called topic_id

I use the following query to SELECT and ECHO the data as follows:

```
$query ="SELECT name, COUNT(replies.topic_id) AS replies, COUNT(comments.topic_id) AS comments
         FROM topics
         LEFT JOIN replies
         ON topics.topic_id = replies.topic_id
         LEFT JOIN comments
         ON topics.topic_id = comments.topic_id";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
   while ($num = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      echo {$num['name']};
      echo {$num['replies']};
      echo {$num['comments']};
   }
}
```

As you can see, there are two replies and one comment for the topic_id number 1

However, it outputs two replies and two comment as below:

```
name       replies     comments
blue        2            2
```

The correct result should be 2 replies and 1 comments.

Can you help me, pls?

Thanks

Comment: Try INNER JOIN instad of LEFT JOIN.
If it does not work try COUNT(DISTINCT(comments.comment_id))

Comment: try running this query from phpmyadmin or another sql tool and remove the counts. I think you'll see that the comments id is being return twice, which would count up to 2. It's being returned twice due to the way your query is written

Comment: @Anthony: I cannt use INNER JOIN because if the topic has no reply and 1 comment, the output will not return the comment. Besides, I tried the DISTINCT function, it returns only one reply and one comment, because it recognizes the topic_id # 2 in the replies table and comment table as the duplicated ones. Hence, it returns only one reply and one comment instead of 2 replies and 1 comment as it should be.

Comment: @mituv16: I cannot move the COUNT() function because if i do it, it return the topic_id value such as 1,2,3. It does not count any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it helps

```
select 
t.name, 
`replies`,
`comments`
from topics t
left join 
( 
    select topic_id,count(reply_id) as `replies`
    from replies
    group by topic_id
)r
on r.topic_id = t.topic_id
left join
(
    select topic_id,count(comment_id) as `comments`
    from comments
    group by topic_id
)c
on c.topic_id = t.topic_id
group by t.name
```

check the demo here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1412f/7

Comment: As you can test it in your link provided, the number of comment returned is 2, but not 1 for the topic name BLUE. So, it's still incorrect. This is what I am trying to ask for your help!

Comment: @ Abhik: Besides, if the topics has no reply but 1 or 2 comments, the number of comments will not be printed because of the INNER JOIN. So, INNER JOIN cannot be used here.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
SELECT name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(replies.reply_id)) AS replies,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(comments.comment_id)) AS comments
 FROM topics
   INNER JOIN replies
     ON topics.topic_id = replies.topic_id
   INNER JOIN comments
     ON topics.topic_id = comments.topic_id
```

Comment: see my comment above for you.